# Powershell | Insert image into specific position in a word document

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I've managed to insert images into my word document, yet can't find any answers online on how to position an image in a specific position.

This is all I have at the moment:

```
    $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $word.visible = $true

    $document = $word.documents.Add()
    $selection = $word.selection        

    $newInline = $selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture($path)
    $newInline.Height = 50
    $newInline.Width = 150
```

Comment: How do you need to find your "specific position" ? E.g. at the selection (which you have), at the before or after the 1st/2nd/nth character/table/paragraph/word, at the first location containing a specified piece of text?

Comment: Well It should be positioned in the top right corner under the header. I'm new to this, so I  thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code is inserting the image as an *InlineShape* object; for the kind of positioning control you require it needs to be inserted as a *Shape* object.

Comment: So I'd be writing "$selection.Shape($path)"? @macropod

Comment: If you have a document that has the image set up how you want it already, having a look at how it is positioned might be a good start.

Comment: «So I'd be writing "$selection.Shape($path)"?» I would'nt be using that. I'd use something like $document.Shapes.AddPicture($path) - together with application of the Left, Top, Width, Height and Anchor attributes.